# User Interface in different language for WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript, jquery

The WYSIWYG for web we have only has English Interface. For Japanese language Interface what will be the appropriate steps to make it. In future, it may requires the other language support.

I am planning in this way-

For Japanese language setting, in the .js file

```
var language={
    "bold":"太字のテキスト",        
    "italic":"斜体文字",
    ..
    ..        
};
```

What do you think, is it a good apporach?

Comment: Am I right that you want to program a web application with an interface in multiple natural languages including japanese?

Comment: search for Resource Files, Localization if using .net environment

Comment: @JanD, yes I am. I was trying to make the user interface for at least two languages. To make the user interface, dynamic text are generated using javascript.

Comment: @Amit 80% of the coding are based on javascript, so I am not sure whether I can use .net localization concept.

Comment: Ok then try one thing, if your pages are using html and jscript then  you can use ajax. create a backend for the contents uses javascript / ajax to render contents. create two db one for japanese domain and another for enlish domain. it will require a extensive use of ajax approach, if you are using static html files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check Eli Grey's post about [Localization in JavaScript](http://eligrey.com/blog/post/localization-in-javascript) where the author presents a localization JavaScript library named l10n.js.